# How to have different peer dependency if my package is installed on expo or bare react-native

Tags: react-native, expo

I have created a package for react-native, which uses  `react-native-linear-gradient` as the peer dependency. Now I want to add support for `expo` too. So I need `expo-linear-gradient` as the peer dependency.

How should I handle the usage in my code?
Is there a way that I change peer dependency on installation or dynamically change the import based on the environment? Or any workaround?